# CuryID Field Error. unable to cast object Int32 to String

Tags: acumatica

I'm having unusual error on my Currency Field where as I just copied it from the Company Screen the BaseCuryID.

[image]

Whereas, both my DAC and Database Field is on a `String`/`Nvarchar`.

**DAC**

[image: DAC]

**Database Field:**

[image]

`Note: I can save it on the database as a string, but when the BLC Retrieves the data that error occurs.`

Comment: Are you sure its on that field? You should also have a CuryInfoID field i think which is an int. If you look at or include the trace details generated in Acumatica that might help too?

Comment: Is there more information in the Trace window?

Comment: You checked DAC and DB field types which is a great first step. In customization project editor you can also check the DB script mapping in menu File->Edit Project XML and check if the field is mapped as String.

Comment: My bad. The problem is finperiodID (facepalm) duplicate attribute for APOpenPeriod attribute. I also declared PXDBString

Answer (score 0):

so stupid of me to declare also on ny other DAC the FinPeriodID. I used the attribute [APOpenPeriod] it seems it already has an attribute for DBType thus giving an error. The tricky part is just the error message whereas it points to currency but it only means the FinPeriodID. I removed my own [PXDBString].
Thanks guys.